# How check WebBrowser completed fully?

Tags: ajax, delphi, twebbrowser

How to check when WebBrowser has fully completed? This code doesn't work for heavy AJAX websites. It will fire before the site has really completed and thus return HTML code while javascript is still running.

I need to check when the website is FULLY completed. This code was tested with http://www.html5test.com

```
procedure Browser_DocumentComplete(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant);
var
  CurWebrowser: IWebBrowser;
  TopWebBrowser: IWebBrowser;
  Document: OleVariant;
  WindowName: string;
begin
  CurWebrowser := pDisp as IWebBrowser;
  TopWebBrowser := (ASender as TEmbeddedWB).DefaultInterface;
  if (CurWebrowser = TopWebBrowser) and not Browser.Busy and (Browser.ReadyState >= READYSTATE_COMPLETE) then begin
    FDocumentLoaded:=True;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A web page which uses Ajax is loaded by the browser and executes JavaScript to update / modify its content.

The client does not know when a "fully completed" state has been reached. Some JavaScript methods might run after a delay, or periodically.

Comment: This isn't really a solution nor a proper answer.

Comment: Why do you think it's not a proper answer ? We can't conjure a solution which might not exist. You can notify your application through a callback from JavaScript when its *initialization* finishes, but that will require to *inject* the navigated page script somehow (if something like *initialization* finishes exists).

Comment: @TLama Yes it is possible with C# http://pastebin.com/gH5dbNHi hopefully you can post an answer so I can accept. :)

Comment: Not in general. Might be for a specific page (which you didn't specified in your question). And that code is utter implementation full of hope that loading is fully completed when the URL argument passed to the `DocumentComplete` event doesn't start with `http://`, `https://` nor is absolute path of originally navigated URL. This is the answer to the question you've asked. If it was for a specific site, then it might have solution, but for this generic topic there's no versatile solution.

Comment: @TLama Please check the question again. The event is triggered before thus giving wrong html response because javascript is still running.

Comment: @TLama I found a solution with jQuery :)